# how to save the particular django model field as encrypted to database?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a user model in Django models, password is one of the field in users table. While saving user the password should be saved to database as encrypted.
I am using Django Rest Framework to post the users and I don't want to use authentication.

Comment: Django's default auth model saves the password as ***hashed password***.  You can use that feature

Comment: Refer this link, [Password management in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/)

Comment: i need without using authentication

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: i want to know how to do it without authentication.

Comment: Here is a simple example of how ***ciphertext*** can be generated. After generating chiphertext, save it to your model field

Comment: where is the sample example bro, i didnot found any sample example

Comment: opps.. my bad .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335726/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Django provides user authentication built-in. Link to official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

To answer your question, considering you don't want to/can't use built-in authentication. You can encrypt the password field using `make_password` function. Django Auth uses the same to encrypt & authenticate user.

Before saving model, set encrypted password to field. Preferably in model class itself.

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
model.password = make_password(plaintext_password)
model.save()
```