# execute Generated password to Database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, database

I want to send a hashed data to the database.thats my data:

```
0MPA00JQ'Q:0TGF6T?>TE)pRc1.kA<<\I<b3@ZaR<BXq].k#1A6mm"`>:s_c<+RjO:,Y$i2`Y;E
```

But because the data has a lot of symbols, I encounter the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> '0MPA00JQ'Q:0TGF6T?>TE)pRc1.kA<<\I<b3@ZaR<BXq].k#1A6mm"`>:s_c<+RjO:,Y$i2`Y;E"",
> "' at line 1

I tried many methods but none of them worked with the same error! Methods I used:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO {}(disc, data) VALUES (""{}"", ""{}"")""".format(tb,hash_for_data(disc),hash_for_data(data))

sql = """INSERT INTO %s(disc, data) VALUES (""%s"", ""%s"")""" % (TABLE, HASHED_DATA_1, HASHED_DATA_2)
```

And a few other methods

Comment: You can try a hack, `encrypt` your `hashed` data and then try to store it!

Comment: @Psycho but how? you can give a refrence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888765/8607640 see this or this https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-strings-in-python/amp/

Comment: @Psycho The data is hashed! I just want to execute to database

Comment: I know it's hashed, but it is consisting of peculiar special characters thus the start and end of the string can't be understood correctly by compiler. So, if you encrypt it again (so that you can decrypt later), it may become a suitable character string

Comment: You could also try storing the hash data as a binary field rather than a text field in your database.

Comment: This seems like a good use of base64 encoding.

Comment: What is the type of the data, and what is the type of the data column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked was to finally hash the hash data:

```
base64.b16encode(HASHED DATA)
```

In this way the output is equal to the digit without the symbol